# Category Page does not view properly

Tags: magento-1.8

I have newbie at Magento and installed 1.8.1 version properly. 
But some how I cannot see the category edit page properly. Other pages can be seen . What the proplem could be?

[image]

**Cache Management page.**

[image]

Comment: your other screenshot is also showing a lot of errors and notices, I guessing the installation failed in the first place. Maybe because it is a clean install you could start over again. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-installing

Comment: I have insalled Magento on Windows 7 platform. Does this cause the problem?

Comment: It should work correctly, have seen it before. But maybe your WAMP settings are incorrect. Increase memory_limit, time_out, drop the database, delete your local.xml and start the installer again. Cannot help you further than this, because it is too much off-topic and I very Linux minded.